# Считать текст с четырех TextInput. React-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

У меня есть 4 textInputa по 1 символу на каждом. Нужно, чтобы в одну переменную было записано значение всех четырех по порядку. Использую функциональный компонент, на каждом input стоит useRef.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow на русском! Чтобы Вам могли помочь и правильно ответили на Ваш вопрос, прикрепите, пожалуйста, свой код. Воспользуйтесь кнопкой *Править* под вопросом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const [a,setA] = useState('')
const [b,setB] = useState('')
....
const c = a+' '+b
//или
const c = useMemo(()=>a+' '+b,[a,b])
....
<TextInput value={a} onChangeText={setA}/>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]